# Bookshelfjs where clause on join

Tags: javascript, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I just started using bookshelfJS, and I couldn't find a clear answer on how to do the following.

Consider I have the following tables:

```
product
--------
id


product_account
--------
id
product_id
account_id


collection
--------
id


collection_product_account
--------
collection_id
product_account_id
```

There can be many products to a collection.

I want to do the following

```
SELECT pa.*, p.* FROM product_account pa 
INNER JOIN collection_product_account cp ON cp.product_account_id = pa.id 
INNER JOIN product p ON p.product_account_id = pa.product_id 
WHERE cp.collection_id = ?
```

How would I be able to pass in a collection id, and return a whole list of product_accounts, and then get products from that?

For reference, I am doing this if I were querying with a product_account_id

```
new productAccountModel()
.where({account_id: 1})
.fetchAll({withRelated: ['product']})
.then(function(productAccounts)
{
  return productAccounts.toJSON());
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming this is your model:

```
var Product = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'product',
    collections: function() {
        return this.belongsToMany(Collection);
    }
});

var Collection = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'collection',
    products: function() {
        return this.belongsToMany(Product);
    }
});
```

Then you have to switch the logic a bit. Once you say `new Product()`, you can't query this by related table. But you can switch it, like this:

```
new Collection({id: 1}).fetch({
    withRelated: ['products']
}).then(function(result) {
    res.json(result.toJSON());
});
```

Does this help?

**Update:**

If necessary, you can additionally attach relations from the model you are attaching, i.e.:

```
new Collection({id: 1}).fetch({
    withRelated: ['products.company']
}).then(function(result) {
    res.json(result.toJSON());
});
```

Comment: So this returns a collection of "Collection" now. How would i make it so that it returns "Product"?

I actually have more related attached to "Product" I would like to attach alongside it. Updating the question to reflect that now.

Comment: Yes this returns a single collection with the desired Id, but you have all the products attached to the response that belong to that collection. If you want to load more stuff related to product, you can add it in withRelated, e.g. 'product.type'

Comment: Ah, `withRelated: [productAccount], [productAccount.product]` gets me closer.  I guess this is probably the best I'll get to it? Was hoping to get it to return one level in at productAccount.  But, I'll just object manipulate after the fact.  Thanks!!

Comment: just to supplement your result answer: `result.map(function(collection) { return collection.toJSON().productAccount; })`